# How do you escape the ~ character in a Batch script?

Tags: batch-file, escaping, special-characters

I am trying to replace a (~) in a string with a comma (,) but using the (~) during string replacement means display all characters from that index (e.g. %a:~2%).

My string is `1,2,3~4~5~6,7~8,9,10`

I have already tried using a caret (^) which doesn't do the job.

With the caret (^) `%a:^~=,%` I get the echo of `1,2,3~4~5~6,7~8,9,10`

Without the caret (^) `%a:~=,%` I get `a:~=,`

Input:

```
1,2,3~4~5~6,7~8,9,10
```

code:

```
SET a=1,2,3~4~5~6,7~8,9,10
SET a=%a:^~=,%
echo !a!
```

Expected Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Actual Output:

`a:~=,` OR `1,2,3~4~5~6,7~8,9,10`

What is the escape character for the (~) so I can replace it in a string?

EDIT: Add more detail about the wider project

I have an excel sheet which contains some cells that contain items like `data, data` this excel sheet is then exported as csv so I can iterate through the data. When the excel is converted the cells that contain `data, data` are converted to `"data, data"`. I have found a work around for keeping that data as one cell when iterating through the .csv with commas (,) by first looping through the line looking for double quotes (") and when they have been found I take the data within the quotes and replace the commas (,) with tildes (~) and remove the double quotes ("). This changes the data to `data~ data`. I then reform the original line with this change. Later I access the data based on input from the user telling me which column of data they want. At this stage I'd like to be able to convert the tildes (~) back to commas (,) so as to return the data exactly as it is shown in the excel sheet i.e. converting `data~ data` into `data, data`

Comment: I completely understand the issue you have, and whilst it is most often necessary for questions to include a [mcve] of code, in this case, solutions would be much easier if taken in the context of an actual task. Can you please expand upon your task so that solutions may be tailored more specifically; thank you.

Comment: well, after your edit, easiest obvious method is to use something other than tilde to replace the comma with?

Comment: Yeah, I'm currenty using the @ symbol to get the same effect and easily escaped with ^@ but I think it'd still be good to know how to escape a tilde (~) as this character is much much less likely to appear in the excel sheet than an @ symbol

Comment: I would suggest using PowerShell instead, which makes lots of things very easy that are impossible or very painful in cmd.exe.

Comment: As above, use a tool designed to work with [tag:csv] content.

Comment: Another good point, but I just feel like there must be an escape character for this. I can continue my work without it but it'd be good to know if ~ is escapable

Comment: @jamesD, I've already told you that **there isn't** there are only workarounds, and apparently they're too bulky for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is currently not a way to escape tilde in batch, but there are some work arounds.

```
@echo off
set a=1,2,3~4~5~6,7~8,9,10
:start
for /f "tokens=1* delims=~" %%i in ("%a%") do set "a=%%i,%%j"
echo %a% | findstr "~">nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% equ 0  goto start
echo %a%
```

Not sure if it needs expanation as it is pretty obvious? but will be glad to explain if needed `:)`

Comment: Thanks for helping, that's a great work around. However it's a bit too bulky for what I want. My current script is already quite hefty, and if possible I'd like to restrict the solution to just replacing the character using %a:~=%.

Comment: @jamesD, it also doesn't work if your string looked like this: `1,2,3~4~~6,7~8,9,10` for instance, because multiple concurrent delimiters are seen as one. **I asked you to post the script for context**, and you didn't bother, **so please do not exclude answers due to your own failure**. You cannot use the tilde in that type of substitution, so you will need a workaround, if you don't want a workaround, then just delete your question, to prevent anyone else's response from being excluded too!

Comment: @Compo _"because multiple concurrent delimiters are seen as one"_ It does in fact still return `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10` but I get your point, the idea here is to get rid of the tilde, so this will :)

Comment: @Compo I have expanded as you had requested, but as I knew it would take me a while to explain, I replied to the above comment first as it was faster to do. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Gerhard, the question asked to "replace **a `~`** with **a `,`**", so the output from `1,2,3~4~~6,7~8,9,10` should be `1,2,3,4,,6,7,8,9,10` not `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10`, which was the point I was trying to make to jamesD.

Comment: @compo. Yes I am aware. I am saying that with the current expected result this works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to escape the `~` character, so you can only work around it.

What about this approach:

```cmd
@echo off
set "STR=1,2,3~4~5~6,7~8,9,10"
set "NEW=,"
:LOOP
if not defined STR goto :END
rem // Get part left from first `~`:
for /F "delims=~ eol=~" %%I in (",%STR%") do set "PRT=%%I"
set "PRT=%PRT:~1%"
rem // Get part right from first `~`:
set "CMP=%STR:*~=%"
if "%CMP%" == "%STR%" (set "STR=") else (set "STR=%CMP%")
rem // Replace a single `~` by `,`:
set "NEW=%NEW%%PRT%,"
goto :LOOP
:END
echo(%NEW:~1,-1%
```